threw an unhandled Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INDEX_CONTENT_TYPE
         logger.info("Started Pushing to Elastic Search");             postTestRunDataRepository.saveAll(allTestCasesWithDetails);             logger.info("Finished Pushing to Elastic Search");

This is where it fails..these are dependencies added for elasticsearch
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.17.24</version>
</dependency>



Can you please [edit] the question and make it a [mcve]?
